# To-Do List | Node, EJS, jQuery | Node can't match the name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ejs

I work on a classic study project : the To-Do List with Node, EJS, jQuery. I'm adding this functionality : when you tick the checkbox, the next time you submit to create a new task, the checked tasks are considered as done. But, it seems that Node cannot match the `checkbox-i-done` name attribute. I use body-parser too. There are slices of code :

index.js

```
app.post("/submit", (req, res) => {

    if (tasks != null) {                                    // Doesn't function from this part...
        for (let i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {

            let checkbox = "checkbox-" + i + "-done";

            if (req.body.checkbox) {
                tasks[i].done = true;
                console.log(tasks[i].title + " : " + tasks[i].done) 
            } else {
                tasks[i].done = false;
                console.log(tasks[i].title + " : " + tasks[i].done)
            }
        }
    }                                                       // To this part.

    class task {
        constructor() {
            this.title = req.body.title,
                this.toDo = Date.now(),
                this.done = false
        }
    }

    let newTask = new task()

    tasks.push(newTask)

    res.render("index.ejs", {
        tasks: tasks,
    })

});
```

ui.js (jQuery part)

```
console.log("jQUery is on.");

const taskDone = () =\> {

    $(".checkbox").on("click", (event) => {
    
        let checkboxId = event.target.id;
        $("#" + checkboxId).closest(".input-group").toggleClass("done");
    
        if ($("#" + checkboxId).attr("name") === undefined) {
            $("#" + checkboxId).attr("name", checkboxId + "-done");
        } else {
            $("#" + checkboxId).removeAttr("name");
        }
    
    })

}

taskDone();
```

index.ejs (view)

```
    <form action="/submit" method="post" class="input-group mb-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Type your new task"
        aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-light" type="submit" id="button-addon2">+</button>
    </form>
    
    <% if(locals.tasks) { %>
    
    <% for(let i = 0; i < locals.tasks.length; i++){ %>
    
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-text">
        <input id="checkbox-<%= [i] %>" class="form-check-input mt-0 checkbox" type="checkbox" value=""
          aria-label="Checkbox for following text input">
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control task-text" aria-label="Text input with checkbox"
        value="<%= locals.tasks[i].title %>" readonly>
    </div>
    
    <% }
    }
    
      else{
    
        } %>
    
    <form action="/reset" method="post" class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end">
      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-reset">Reset List</button>
    </form>
```

Note : The frontend is a big part of Bootstrap.
You can find the **repo** there on the main branch: https://github.com/sambarnades/todo/tree/main

I tried to `console.log()` a lot of things but I really don't find where's the bug. Sure that the loop works but it seems that Node cannot reach the name attribute to update the array in the server.